# Save array in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to save extra information before sending the total order to Paypal. For each item I have created a single column in my MySQL database where I want to store it. Now I was thinking to save it as an array which I can read later for creating a PHP page. Extra fields are taken from input form fields.

By using an array can I be sure not to mixup information?

Comment: "I have a column for each item" ... do you mean row or?

Comment: storing an array in a single mysql field defeats the purpose of a database. What does your current code look like?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.8 and higher has now native JSON support, meaning you can put a JSON string directly in a table field in the database.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can store the array using [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)/[`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize). With that solution they cannot easily be used from other programming languages, so you may consider using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)/[`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) instead (which gives you a widely supported format). *Avoid* using `implode`/`explode` for this since you'll probably end up with bugs or security flaws.

Note that this makes your table non-normalized, which may be a bad idea since you cannot easily query the data. Therefore consider this carefully before going forward. May you need to query the data for statistics or otherwise? Are there other reasons to normalize the data?

Also, don't save the raw `$_POST` array. Someone can easily make their own web form and post data to your site, thereby sending a really large form which takes up lots of space. Save those fields you want and make sure to validate the data before saving it (so you won't get invalid values).

Comment: please could you elaborate on the security flaws surrounding `implode()` and `explode()`.

Comment: verbumSapienti, consider this piece of code: `implode(':', ['12','34','5:6'])` which results in this string: `12:34:5:6`. This should not happen in the first place if  you have proper input validation (so that no value can ever be `5:6`), but it is also always better to use functions that are parameterized and/or always outputs valid unambiguous data, such as json_encode.

Comment: Firstly there is a misspell in your answer (should be serialize not serialise). Secondly the serialize/unserialize is the standard way to store whole structures as strings in PHP. You can serialize objects including their properties etc. JSON is the best if you only want to store arrays as it is the most compatible solution to use outside PHP. You can easily read JSON in Javascript or other languages.

Answer (score 21):

The way things like that are done is with **serializing** the array, which means "making a string out of it". To better understand this, have a look on this:

```
$array = array("my", "litte", "array", 2);

$serialized_array = serialize($array); 
$unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array); 

var_dump($serialized_array); // gives back a string, perfectly for db saving!
var_dump($unserialized_array); // gives back the array again
```

Comment: FYI these days it's also possible to save arrays as JSON directly into a MySQL database (and other database types too for sure). MySQL is then able to read the JSON as a string AND as real array data. This is useful, but slow, but might be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 13):

Use the PHP function `serialize()` to convert arrays to strings. These strings can easily be stored in MySQL database. Using `unserialize()` they can be converted to arrays again if needed.

Comment: before save

    $store = serizalize($someData);
    $sql = "insert into PaypalLogs (`store`, `created`) value ('{$store}', NOW())";

after

    $someData = unserizalize($row['store']);

Answer (score 13):

**To convert any array (or any object) into a string using PHP, call the serialize():**

```
$array = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$string = serialize( $array );
echo $string;
```

**$string will now hold a string version of the array. The output of the above code is as follows:**

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}
```

**To convert back from the string to the array, use unserialize():**

```
// $array will contain ( 1, 2, 3 )
$array = unserialize( $string );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$myArray = new array('1', '2');
$seralizedArray = serialize($myArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store it in multi valued column with a comma separator in an RDBMs table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL JSON datatype to store the array

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

To get the above object in PHP

```
json_encode(["key1"=> "value1", "key2"=> "value2"]);
```

More in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html