# Inserting JSON to DB Using Model in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to use the model create option and this is my array:

```
$result = array(
            'match_id' => $input['id'],
            'score' =>  $input['score'],
            'result' =>  $input['result'],
            'headline' =>  NULL,
            'article' =>  $input['report'],
            'tries' =>  $input['try'],
            'try_amount' =>  $input['tryquant'],
            'conversions' =>  $input['conv'],
            'conv_amount' =>  $input['convquant'],
            'penalties' =>  $input['pens'],
            'pen_amount' =>  $input['penquant'],
            'dropgoals' =>  $input['dgs'],
            'dg_amount' =>  $input['dgquant']
            );

Result::create($result);
```

The contents of some of these are arrays themselves. eg:

```
$input['penquant'] = [
"4"
]
```

When I run my code, it saves the data to the DB simply as Array and throws up the following error:

ErrorException in helpers.php line 703: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It's correct that you send key -> value pairs for saving. On other side, the values needs to be string. Use serialize/unserialize php functions. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database

Comment: Thank you @shamanSK, I've been a fool!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have rushed, forgot to use json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use mutators and accessors in your model.

example of mutator

```
// convert pen_amount from snake case to studly case
// The set...attribute (the ... is you field name which is in studly case) helps transform the data before you save it 
// into the database
public function setPenAmountAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['pen_amount'] = serialize($value);
}
```

example of an accessor is

```
// convert pen_amount from snake case to studly case
// the get...Attribute (the ... is you field name which is in studly case) helps you convert the data back to it original state
public function getPenAmountAttribute($value)
{
    return unserialize($value);
}
```

You can use accessors and mutators for all your fields that you want to save as array. This is elegant. No need to manually use json_encode and decode in your controllers.