# Insert or Take Associative array from Database (POST/GET)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I have been thinking that it could spare some time if it was possible to insert and remove `associative` array in and out of a database. (using `MySQL`)

I would imagine if you wanted to insert just a numeric array, you could `implode` and `explode` them using different characters for the differences if you wanted to insert or take out `(POST/GET)` them from the database, but would an associative array be any different?

Would it be an entry like `name=jack,age=15` then explode the `,` and iterate through the two pieces of `name=jack` and `age=15`? Or are there better methods for doing this? Like a MySQL tag of some sort.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your goal? I don't see clear connection between http POST/GET and (My)SQL in your question.

Comment: Being able to store associative arrays in a database. I'm just asking if there's a specific way to do this than the way I wanted to do it :) @rudolf_franek

Comment: In general it is possible to do what you suggest and there are more than one different options. If your idea suits you then just go ahead and use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database