# What is the best way to save and edit array in database (json, serialize or text)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to add information to my clients, for example the number of actions they are entitled to perform

I read on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database) that we can use the `serialize()` or `json_encode()` function to save the array in database

**But why not save it directly in text format like this**: `["view", "edit", "delete", "save"]`?

**With the json and serialize functions, how to add or delete data?**
For example with json_encode, I have to make a data `json_decode()` and make an `unset()` or `array_push()` then `json_encode()`? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: *"But why not save it directly in text format like this"* – Well, JSON or the PHP format produced by `serialize` *are* text formats which can easily be converted to/from native PHP arrays… So you can manipulate PHP arrays using array functions and store the results to/from text. I'm unclear what I/you are missing here…?

Comment: So you should consider amending you database design and keeping this data in a seperate table the items of which are linked to the owning information. Try a few [database design tutorials](https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) before going any further

Comment: "better" is a bit subjective and somewhat dependent on your business requirements. You say "why not save it directly in text format like this: ["view", "edit", "delete", "save"]"...but actually the example you've given is valid JSON as it happens. JSON _is_ a text format. It's a well-understood one with ready-made serialising and deserialising functions. I don't see any point in inventing your own text format when that one works well. But you might also consider whether creating a proper relational table structure to store your data is a better way to go in terms of querying it later.

Answer (score 5):

> I read on another post that we can use the serialize() or json_encode() function to save the array in database

That isn't entirely accurate. You can use those functions to convert the array to a string. You could then save the string in a database field.

This is Not A Good Idea™ as it means you can't sensibly search on the data in the array. You should make use of the relational nature of databases and set up a real (e.g. [many-to-many](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/27291/many-to-many-relationship)) relationship.

> But why not save it directly in text format like this: ["view", "edit", "delete", "save"]?

Because an array is **not** a text format (and if that is text, then that is the output that `json_encode` would give you).

> With the json and serialize functions, how to add or delete data? For example with json_encode, I have to make a data json_decode() and make an unset() or array_push() then json_encode()?

Yes

> Or is there a better way to do it?

See the earlier note about relationships.