# Pass $_SESSION to database

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble passing a variable to a database using an `insert into` statement. Im trying to execute a statement and also insert the `$ses`variable into my database.

My code:

```
 session_start();
 $ses = $_SESSION['uid'];`
```

My SQL statement:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO narocila (nameNarocilo, priceNarocilo, nameNarocnik) VALUES
          ((SELECT nameTaco, priceTaco FROM taco
          WHERE idTaco = $idTaco), $ses)";  
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried echoing $sql? `echo $sql;` before calling mysqli_query()?

Comment: To save objects or arrays - $_SESSION is an array - to the database you need to serialize them.This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database

Comment: What's `$idTaco`? This query is all wrong. You can't use `VALUES` and then a select statement, and in addition, you don't expose any error messages. If `mysqli_query` is returns false, you should check `mysqli_error` to get the error of the database. Additional debugging steps: echo out `$sql` and run it manually via something like phpmyadmin or the console, and inspect any error messages.

Comment: it prints out the right session id that is supposed to be inserted into the database if thats what u thought. thanks

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that $idTaco and $ses  are two integer values 
you could use an insert select and a prepared  statement  (for avoid sqlinjection ) and manage the assigmento of param values

assuming that $idTaco and $ses | $_SESSION['uid']  are two integer values 
you could use an insert select and a prepared  statement  (for avoid sqlinjection ) and manage the assigmento of param values

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO narocila (nameNarocilo, priceNarocilo, nameNarocnik) 
        select nameTaco, priceTaco, ? 
        from taco
        WHERE idTaco = ?;" ;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql ) ;
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii",$_SESSION['uid'], $idTaco);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

or  directly

Comment: Wow thank you! u are a life saver! Gotta research some more about prepared statements. Thanks a lot for help. have a nice day :)