# Laravel: insert array object in single SQL column

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a single column in db named session and I want to insert all below data in single column in a form of array.

**data available in array**

```
 array:1 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
"_token" => "ENzbpMgvlOhMkwE1Fv13hjn9NlCOUolIFBDZ4wJd"
"session_start" => "2000-01-01"
"session_end" => "2002-01-01"
]
]
```

**I tried below**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $arr = (array($request->all()));

  $create = SchoolSession::create($arr));
}
```

getting an error: **Array to string conversion**

Please advise the solution and also advise how to fetch the same from db and show seperately.

Comment: please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert an array into a database field without some kind of serialization, so you may try something like this (but there's a better way, continue reading):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $json = json_encode($request->all());

    $create = SchoolSession::create(['session' => $json]);
}
```

Make sure your database field type is `JSON/TEXT` depending on your `mysql` version. When retrieving the data you also need to `decode` it.

Out of the box, [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) provides an easy mechanism to handle this. So, you don't need to manually `encode/decode` your data. `Eloquent` will take care of encoding brfore saving it to database and also the decoding will be handled automatically. Read the doc (link given above).

Comment: I used json_encode to insert it works but when i use decode its showing me data ins this form  
        
        
        
        
        
     {"_token":"ENzbpMgvlOhMkwE1Fv13hjn9NlCOUolIFBDZ4wJd","session_start":"2000-01-01","session_end":"2002-01-01"}

Comment: Follow the [Mutations/Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Comment: To decode a `json` string to an array, you should use `json_decode($data, true)`. This will return an array instead of an object ([stdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)).

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly add array in the column:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $arr = $request->all();
    $arr = serialize($arr);
    $create = SchoolSession::create(['session'=>$arr]);
}
```

And to fetch the same from DB:

```
public function view(Request $request)
{

    $SchoolSession = SchoolSession::where('id','Specific ID ADD')->get();
    $SchoolSession = unserialize($SchoolSession[0]->session);
}
```

Comment: getting error Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Routing\serialize()

Comment: @MuhammadKazim Which laravel version have you used?