# How to use an array in sequelize and express js

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

How to create a sequelize (sql dialect) model with array and how to perform push/pop operations.
Can anyone share code snippets.

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686474/12761193

Answer (score 0):

According to Sequelize docs ARRAY type can be used only in PostgreSQL:

> DataTypes.ARRAY(/* DataTypes.SOMETHING */)  // Defines an array of DataTypes.SOMETHING. PostgreSQL only.

See [Other data types](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But,I want to use array in mysql dialect

Comment: Sequelize does not support ARRAY type of field for MySQL as I mentioned in my answer