# MySql: The customer has multiple addresses only one is primary

Tags: mysql

I don't think I planned and organized the table well, so please consider and advise me how to solve this.

In my application I have to ensure that customers can have multiple addresses only one of those addresses must be marked as primary. The primary address is used as the delivery address, etc.

I have `customer` table and i create new relation table `customer_addresses`.

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_addresses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `custemer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_adddrss` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `custemer_id_UNIQUE` (`custemer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `primary_UNIQUE` (`primary_adddrss`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table must contain all the addresses of all customers but only one address from a specific customer must be primary and customer can have only one primary address. That is reson whay i put two unique index.

If i remove `custemer_id` unique only one primary address can be in whole table for all customers.

Only one primary address per customer other non-primary addresses are null.

**Table**

```
id    |   customer_id    | primary_address   |  address
--------------------------------------------------------
1             1                 1               Test
```

This above customer have only one primary address. Now i want to insert for the some customer more non-primary addresses.

**When i try to insert**

```
  INSERT INTO `table`.`customer_addresses`(`id`,`custemer_id`,`primary_adddrss`,`address`)
    VALUES (1, null ,'Test 2');
```

**I get error**

```
1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'primary_UNIQUE'
```

If i remove `primary_UNIQUE` than all cusomers can have only one primary. I need one customer only one primary.

How to redesign table to slove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the customer may have a lot of different addresses then you have 1:N relation. Create separate addresses table which refers to customers table. Add a column which marks primary address and restrict with only one mark per customer_id.

Schematically (no syntax):

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer ( customer_id PRIMARY KEY, ... );

CREATE TABLE address ( address_id PRIMARY KEY,
                               -- reference to customer
                       customer_id NOT NULL REFERENCES customer (customer_id),
                               -- can be either 1 or NULL
                       is_primary BOOLEAN NULL CHECK (is_primary = 1),
                               -- allows one 1 and many NULL per customer
                       UNIQUE (customer_id, is_primary),
                       ... );
```

---

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e17416b99526d196088ea6a86e03f2e)

Comment: thanks for answer. First like you can see my schema is the some. When i put two uniqe column i get `1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'custemer_id_UNIQUE'`. I dont know how but before this i already do this many times. With this unique of the customer_id i cant have two rows with id `1`

Comment: I think if i put two `UNIQUE (customer_id, is_primary)` mysql engine need to mach tow columns to see if the some no only one. In my solution mysql mach only one column if in one col is value exists in other that fails.

Comment: @Ivan customer_id is not unique. You can create a combination key (customer_id, address) to be unique if needed.

Comment: Yes i make combination of two keys `customer_id, primary_address` and engine not allow me to insert  two the some customer with two different `primary_address`.   1) `ID 1: customer ID = 1: primary_address: 1  ` nest row `ID `2: customer_id = 1; primary_address = null` it fails.

Comment: @Ivan DEMO fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 :**

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_addresses` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`primary_address` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`addresses` TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

you can save primary address in `primary_address` column, and other addresses is saved in `addresses` column as [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686333/save-array-in-mysql-database#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20PHP%20function%20serialize,to%20arrays%20again%20if%20needed.)

---

**Option 2 :**

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_addresses` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL , 
`is_primary` BOOLEAN NOT NULL , 
`addresses` TEXT NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

just save all address as usual, and marks the primary address with is_primary=1 and the non-primary address with is_primary=0